# 301 Redirect URL with Trailing Slash to "Sub directory" with same name

Tags: redirect, subdirectory, slash, trailing

The company I work for recently took over a site that is built in WordPress, apparently Google has indexed several pages with a trailing / that coupled with the fact that the previous company programmer made the site require some information from the URL.

So, Google has indexed domain.com/featured-something/something/ and I need to redirect these pages to domain.com/featured-something/something/?something=something&somethingelse=something else

I tried this code for a redirect, but only works without the trailing slash:

```
RewriteRule ^featured-something/something?$ http://domain.com/featured-something/something/?start=0&pt=&bed=&bat=&subdiv=Aqua&sub=&pr=&display=quick [R=301,L]
```

I had added some code before all of the rules to redirect to a non slashed version first, then these, but that created an infinite redirect loop.

Can someone please help me out?

Thanks

Karl

p.s. The GET string is unique to each different URL, unfortunately, so will have to create rules for each url.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I never gave up the search, even after I posted here.. Looks a little inelegant, but I found a way to make it work (thanks in part to another Stack Overflow question/answer)  Before each and every RewriteRule I had to add a RewriteCond to not rewrite the URL W/ the query string

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !([^&]+&)*start=0(&.*)?$
```

I also changed the ? in the Rule to a /

No more infinite loop and redirects all of Google's indexed pages properly.